# no such option: --include for pybot

Tags: python, tags, automated-tests, robotframework

I am trying to run test cases based on tags. However I get the following error for pybot. Anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

```
run.py: error: no such option: --include
```

I run it as follows `pybot --include Login login.robot`

Documentation is here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names

Comment: I guess you've included an option, `--include`, that it doesn't actually support. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: the option exists. It's in the document. I run it ass follows

pybot --include Login login.robot

Comment: **Edit the question**. Including a link to the documentation would probably help, too.

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#by-tag-names

Comment: ... **in the question**, you donut.

Comment: If you do `pybot --help`, what does it show? Is it possible you have another script in your path named "pybot" that isn't the robot test runner?

Comment: Your title says "pybot", but the error message shows "run.py", which is not "pybot". Are you _sure_ this is a question about pybot?

Answer (score 0):

I run `pybot` like this and it works:

```
pybot --include ready C:\path\to\TestSuites\TestSuiteName.txt
```

`ready` is the name of my tag

instead of `login.robot` I put the path to the test suite file I want to run.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I may have solved this if in your library you were using the optparse python library. If you were, try removing this and you should be ok.

Have added an issue to Robot Framework:
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2173

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does solve it; there's a very high chance that the error was caused by using the optparse library within a test; the error raised by this is handled erroneously by the Robot framework... Remove optparse should fix the problem...
"what might be wrong?" -> Using optparse within a test